# Postgres error while running database script

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm getting this error. Could anyone please suggest to sort this out.

```
[root@ backup-scripts]# ./ran-database-daily.sh pg_dump: invalid option -- 'O' 
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete contents of the shell script as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. ([edit] your question, please do not put code in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Try `-O`:

```
pg_dump --help
pg_dump dumps a database as a text file or to other formats.

Usage:
  pg_dump [OPTION]... [DBNAME]

General options:
  -f, --file=FILENAME          output file or directory name
  -F, --format=c|d|t|p         output file format (custom, directory, tar,
                               plain text (default))
  -j, --jobs=NUM               use this many parallel jobs to dump
  -v, --verbose                verbose mode
  -V, --version                output version information, then exit
  -Z, --compress=0-9           compression level for compressed formats
  --lock-wait-timeout=TIMEOUT  fail after waiting TIMEOUT for a table lock
  --no-sync                    do not wait for changes to be written safely to disk
  -?, --help                   show this help, then exit

Options controlling the output content:
  -a, --data-only              dump only the data, not the schema
  -b, --blobs                  include large objects in dump
  -B, --no-blobs               exclude large objects in dump
  -c, --clean                  clean (drop) database objects before recreating
  -C, --create                 include commands to create database in dump
  -E, --encoding=ENCODING      dump the data in encoding ENCODING
  -n, --schema=PATTERN         dump the specified schema(s) only
  -N, --exclude-schema=PATTERN do NOT dump the specified schema(s)
  -O, --no-owner               skip restoration of object ownership in
                               plain-text format
  -s, --schema-only            dump only the schema, no data
  -S, --superuser=NAME         superuser user name to use in plain-text format
  -t, --table=PATTERN          dump the specified table(s) only
  -T, --exclude-table=PATTERN  do NOT dump the specified table(s)
  -x, --no-privileges          do not dump privileges (grant/revoke)
  --binary-upgrade             for use by upgrade utilities only
  --column-inserts             dump data as INSERT commands with column names
  --disable-dollar-quoting     disable dollar quoting, use SQL standard quoting
  --disable-triggers           disable triggers during data-only restore
  --enable-row-security        enable row security (dump only content user has
                               access to)
  --exclude-table-data=PATTERN do NOT dump data for the specified table(s)
  --extra-float-digits=NUM     override default setting for extra_float_digits
  --if-exists                  use IF EXISTS when dropping objects
  --inserts                    dump data as INSERT commands, rather than COPY
  --load-via-partition-root    load partitions via the root table
  --no-comments                do not dump comments
  --no-publications            do not dump publications
  --no-security-labels         do not dump security label assignments
  --no-subscriptions           do not dump subscriptions
  --no-synchronized-snapshots  do not use synchronized snapshots in parallel jobs
  --no-tablespaces             do not dump tablespace assignments
  --no-unlogged-table-data     do not dump unlogged table data
  --on-conflict-do-nothing     add ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING to INSERT commands
  --quote-all-identifiers      quote all identifiers, even if not key words
  --rows-per-insert=NROWS      number of rows per INSERT; implies --inserts
  --section=SECTION            dump named section (pre-data, data, or post-data)
  --serializable-deferrable    wait until the dump can run without anomalies
  --snapshot=SNAPSHOT          use given snapshot for the dump
  --strict-names               require table and/or schema include patterns to
                               match at least one entity each
  --use-set-session-authorization
                               use SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION commands instead of
                               ALTER OWNER commands to set ownership

Connection options:
  -d, --dbname=DBNAME      database to dump
  -h, --host=HOSTNAME      database server host or socket directory
  -p, --port=PORT          database server port number
  -U, --username=NAME      connect as specified database user
  -w, --no-password        never prompt for password
  -W, --password           force password prompt (should happen automatically)
  --role=ROLENAME          do SET ROLE before dump

If no database name is supplied, then the PGDATABASE environment
variable value is used.

Report bugs to <pgsql-bugs@lists.postgresql.org>.
```